# non-retriable error returned from app while processing pub/sub event when using declarative way

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, azureservicebus, publish-subscribe, dapr

[image]

I'm getting an error like this when i try to consume a topic using DAPR pub/sub. It looks like the message is consumed successfully, but an error is logged just before. Couldn't identify the root-cause. The issue happens only if I use declarative way of subscription. If we use the [Topic] annotation instead, no error is logged. I tried using different message brokers like rabbitMQ, redis, azure message bus. The case is same for all.
Here's the configuration I use

```
pubsub.yml
# apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
# kind: Component
# metadata:
# name: pubsub
# spec:
# type: pubsub.redis
# version: v1
# metadata:
# - name: redisHost
# value: redis:6379
# - name: actorStateStore
# value: "true"
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: pubsub
spec:
type: pubsub.azure.servicebus.topics
version: v1
metadata:
  - name: connectionString
    value: 
Endpoint=sb://daprpocservicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageShared AccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxx

subscription.yml
apiVersion: dapr.io/v2alpha1
kind: Subscription
metadata:
name: pubsub
spec:
topic: weatherforecasttopic
routes:
default: /consume
pubsubname: pubsub
scopes:
  - daprpublisher
  - daprconsumer
```

And I'm publishing the values like this

```
await _daprClient.PublishEventAsync<WeatherForecast[]>(PubsubName, TopicNameOfWeatherForecast, forecast);
```

I'm stuck here. Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the function body. How have you set the route for this function? I am also getting 404 . Is "/consume" actually your function name. Also where have you defined the scope "daprpublisher"

Comment: /consume is the route for the function in consumerservice. under scope you need to specify only the consumer service name. in my case 'daprconsumer'. will add the sample in the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue. I was getting the error since I have added both daprpublisher and
daprconsumer services under the scopes. And the /consume endpoint was only available in the consumer.

But still getting a couple of 404 errors : GET /dapr/config : 404, GET /dapr/subscribe : 404 on application start-up. Need to investigate it further.

**Update:**
Code sample

```
scopes:
  - daprconsumer
```

in controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/consume")]
public ActionResult<bool> Consume([FromBody] WeatherForecast[] forecast)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to the 404 on the GET /dapr/config. This endpoint is for Actors (https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/actors/actor-reentrancy/) but we are not using this and still getting the same message.